# Get specified columns data from Cassandra database not all the columns data

Tags: java, cassandra, pelops

I am working with Cassandra database. I have created one column family which has 10 columns in that.

Now I am interested in retrieving only the columns that I required. I don't need to retrieve all the columns value from the Cassandra database.

Suppose if I have below columns in my column family `users`.

```
colA
colB
colC
colD
```

And I need to get only `colA and colB` data from Cassandra database. Then what I am supposed to do? I don't want to get all the columns data from Cassandra and then loop around to get the required columns.

Something like-

`SELECT colA, colB from table1;`

I am working with `Pelops client`.

Below is my code.

```
public void readTest() {
        // read back the data we just wrote
        Selector selector = Pelops.createSelector(poolName);
        List<Column> columns = selector.getColumnsFromRow(colFamilyName, rowKey, false, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

        System.out.println("Name: " + Selector.getColumnStringValue(columns, "name"));
        System.out.println("Age: " + Selector.getColumnValue(columns, "age").toInt());

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a getColumnsFromRow call which takes a "SlicePredicate" to specify the column names.
Such as:

```
getColumnsFromRow(String columnFamily, Bytes rowKey, SlicePredicate colPredicate, ConsistencyLevel cLevel)
```

Comment: Thanks Zanson for the suggestion. But in your above syntax, I cannot find where should I specify column names that I want to retrieve? Can you provide a simple example for that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: in the colPredicate. For instance

SlicePredicate myPredicate = Selector.newColumnsPredicate("mycol1", "mycol2");